# Need help answer checking combinations and permutations problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

I was doing some problems for my quiz earlier today (which is now concluded) and went through some combination problems I'm unsure I answered correctly. If I'm wrong, can someone please explain why to me.

Letters = {a, b, c}

Create a string of length 25.

1) String must have exactly 9 A's.

**My answer:** C(25, 9) or (25!/9!)

2) String starts with 3 As and ends with 2 Bs

**My answer:** 3^(20)

Are these correct?

Comment: I think you've missed placing out letters in the other positions. Your answer to (1) is $C(25, 9)$, which describes merely the process of picking out 9 places for "a". There are $2^{25 - 9} = 2^{16}$ for the rest because there are only 2 choices for the rest. The complete answer should be $C(25, 9)\cdot 2^{16}$. The answer for (2) is correct, I think.

Comment: Ugh.. thank you. I was thinking about that...

Answer (score 1):

No. For the first, your two options are not the same.  I could argue the answer to 1 is zero.  a is not the same as A, so no strings on $\{a,b,c\}$ have 9 $A$'s.  Frequently we use a and A as related but different items.  Assuming you don't care between lower case and capitals, $C(25,9)$ chooses the locations for the $A$'s, but each of the rest has two choices.  Your answer for 2 is fine.  You have five locations that are specified and twenty that are free.

Comment: Thank you. It;s a little disappointing knowing that since the question was parted I missed the next seceding parts as well.